# GCC -Wdangling-pointer correct or bug?

Tags: c++, gcc, gcc-warning

I ran into some code that builds a linked list on the stack and via destructors cleans up correctly AFAICT

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

class TIntermNode {
  public:
    TIntermNode(const std::string& name, const std::vector<TIntermNode*>& children) : name(name), children(children) {
    };
    const std::string name;
    const std::vector<TIntermNode*> children;
};

class TIntermRebuild
{
  public:
    TIntermRebuild() {};
    virtual ~TIntermRebuild();
    void rebuild(TIntermNode &node);

  private:
    void traverseAny(TIntermNode &currNode);
    void traversePre(TIntermNode &currNode);
    void traverseChildren(TIntermNode &currNode);
    void traversePost(TIntermNode &currNode);

    void printStack(const char* msg);

    struct NodeStackGuard;

    template <typename T>
    struct ConsList
    {
        T value;
        ConsList<T> *tail;
    };

    ConsList<TIntermNode *> mNodeStack{nullptr, nullptr};
};

struct TIntermRebuild::NodeStackGuard
{
    ConsList<TIntermNode*> oldNodeStack;
    ConsList<TIntermNode*> &nodeStack;
    NodeStackGuard(ConsList<TIntermNode *> &stack, TIntermNode *str)
        : oldNodeStack(stack), nodeStack(stack)
    {
        nodeStack = {str, &oldNodeStack};
    }
    ~NodeStackGuard() { nodeStack = oldNodeStack; }
};

TIntermRebuild::~TIntermRebuild() {}

void TIntermRebuild::printStack(const char* msg)
{
    std::cout << msg;
    ConsList<TIntermNode*>* node = &mNodeStack;
    while (node) {
        if (node->value) {
            std::cout << node->value->name << "->";
        }
        node = node->tail;
    }
    std::cout << "(e)\n";
}

// PS: comment the next line out and the warning goes away
#define printStack(msg)

void TIntermRebuild::traversePre(TIntermNode &originalNode)
{
    printStack("traversePre before:");
    NodeStackGuard guard(mNodeStack, &originalNode);
    printStack("traversePre after:");
}

void TIntermRebuild::traversePost(TIntermNode &currNode)
{
    printStack("traversePost before:");
    NodeStackGuard guard(mNodeStack, &currNode);
    printStack("traversePost after:");
}

void TIntermRebuild::traverseChildren(TIntermNode &currNode)
{
    printStack("traverseChildren before:");
    NodeStackGuard guard(mNodeStack, &currNode);

    for (auto node : currNode.children)
    {
        traverseAny(*node);
    }
    printStack("traverseChildren After:");
}

void TIntermRebuild::traverseAny(TIntermNode &currNode)
{
    traversePre(currNode);
    traverseChildren(currNode);
    traversePost(currNode);
}

void TIntermRebuild::rebuild(TIntermNode &currNode)
{
    traverseAny(currNode);
}

int main()
{
    TIntermRebuild rebuild;

    TIntermNode grandChild1("grandChild1", {});

    TIntermNode child1("child1", {&grandChild1});
    TIntermNode child2("child2", {});

    TIntermNode root("root", {&child1, &child2});
    rebuild.rebuild(root);
}
```

To explain what's happening. At the bottom a singally linked list "stack" is started.
`NodeStackGuard` contains ConsList (oldNodeStack) and a reference to an existing ConsList. I copyes existing ConsList and then points the existing one to its copy. This way it builds up a singally  linked list on the stack. It's destuctor restores the previous ConsList so on exit it's back to the way it started.

The issue is, with `-Wdangling-pointer` GCC complains

```
Compiler stderr
In constructor 'TIntermRebuild::NodeStackGuard::NodeStackGuard(TIntermRebuild::ConsList<TIntermNode*>&, TIntermNode*)',
    inlined from 'void TIntermRebuild::traverseChildren(TIntermNode&)' at <source>:87:47:
<source>:47:19: warning: storing the address of local variable 'guard' in '*(TIntermRebuild::ConsList<TIntermNode*>*)((char*)this + 8).TIntermRebuild::ConsList<TIntermNode*>::tail' [-Wdangling-pointer=]
   47 |         nodeStack = {str, &oldNodeStack};
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>: In member function 'void TIntermRebuild::traverseChildren(TIntermNode&)':
<source>:87:20: note: 'guard' declared here
   87 |     NodeStackGuard guard(mNodeStack, &currNode);
      |                    ^~~~~
<source>:87:20: note: '<unknown>' declared here
```

[see here](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCAAbACcpAAOqAqETgwe3r56KWmOAkEh4SxRMQm2mPYFDEIETMQEWT5%2BXJXVGXUNBEVhkdFxABy29Y3NOW0Koz3BfaUDsYMAlLaoXsTI7BzmAMzByN5YANQmO25OU8SYrKfYJhoAgrv7h5gnZwqX1yy3909mewYBy8x1ObgAbpgHCRfo8/gcmJ8jgAVACSgmiLFCGDeJgA7FZHkcjkkvBFaHhkCA/sTiWiMcQsTiIGgGFMjlN0CAQJdgsBzLEjsw2KQjqz2ZzuZDocQwfSCJjsVgAFS/MyC5AIOjoK4MJZHEBC1iYCDCzArMVa2g6xgsq02vUnAk02n4gAip0JD1pYoEEoIXJ5BGIfKNbE9LuJ4oIHIDUqhRFlZ3lipxqp22Et2t1EbheI9Oy98IMSJTjIASpgIl5tX98V7iaTyZTqUTaWWWJXq9qIPr6%2B7c97aeC8I0vGIjgA/DtdmvW3uDn3g1B4dBHK7d%2BcdpW49UMHFLQcupIh8FMBWtofE5ero7BpiQ4hKB4MACeEG3OJO6uQ62IO8PQtIyOG813vR8lGUK4P3RBVGR3b9Yl/Yh/wPRdhxXMDiAfaIlDce1dRghkmVBH8/wA9Dr0wu9sIglRUgIIi4JI3ckPItCgLhNsqNvE9gmEepkAAaxZP0Y01BplSOFgFGAQCi242NiC8Bwjh3LphIAcXHYh0CPRSFRYJIDAVd43AIV8kkYY0UVhK8lJUmMPDZIIpmA/tFJ9ZEQLELxMEon0jmchRXIIOVbiOZV6joAKB04p5FOC0K5Vg1NjnTTMWI0oT6wYLxaFoJJg1FPKCqK2V8yPSr4r%2BS5HJRVKKyrOdA3UwShO0ho9LzBtaSSvA3OTRqWIyo5PHQNqmGEgL%2BsGtxPxVCKBX3LBsoCyatJ09AIFmsKhuIhDRoFKYpqE0UFreZVLkPTzaUNcaNpEk7hItFbMGyiBnqEm77I8%2ByfTe7L3jdJ0LEuUUBQenE1uq3riQHRTJ0ezrdN7UGhWh9rgbG61Hs9J0PTzAsFIeGdmu1blp2G2cez7Z1Kq4h5QIa4iaetbk%2BMED7o0tSTpNkn6/p9SUUDWGMwTBfn%2BXin1dpSg601uKS3uxgUsvagKAHcrTeU0D1B4CfTwKgjj1rAAFpbjPbxzQN27AtjQM0C8cWzklt7LYza2/M97AzTMyXzDMX2g4Cn0Ef%2B2kVdOEGPduaLaFihn7JF53XbcQOzDMCBzRMABWNwGFDmrk7%2BAB6MujmUIRDTQFg2EEO8EDeEJVBjCkQjGl2jkMMDm6OTWGgYUNgFQTAFB7wfXzrAEsBoTvOYE06IBkuS60eZmyc3QNwNwlRoIuxCSDwYBgjECieuAxePqD3en33t4on4K5qSz%2BTgORrajmALaV8eiH1TH1PswWgFEZa0mvu1CAt9aJ7ygm8JgVA4KvzMO/Im68mbUS3i1bkd9IIMSYmlViyFUJYEFs6RSkDl4wJwvfZQDEjhPxIOwIOaD7Kfy6t/X%2B6tToALYihMBcMSQhi5lAmhdF6HskQcg1hVVCYJUwbebBFMQB4MwPhbMtpD4ChIRfJ4FD7JUOEtArOaiNHWl1IwzAz8WFv3WpjU6KM1w/y6n/Bxwk%2BG6I4iTH0z9TZMBdqgDGxxa7sSwAAOk1JovU7kDEO2JGol875lRvTYeHZOPojEiXEXvcxDojgPCQQMWRJd5F/E3tTcm7NVGwPvkkwh8Evw6LCbnS%2BBlamQWgl4shAUzEEVtN03O4CEkdPolMFkLS2ER3KVgyp29uQbhag0liiFBnkKEYkt8EyBHeLrKXR4/FpJMGCAuNp9llHWnXFUvSNVFKH2ANhBg7h7RcBMWYB5vc8lcCDhDembopl3OGghKJ1pXlBxBegb5WdflWHVB8p5Xz3RpPbECr8ELs7gvtGYH5Bt8wAvOai44xBUCoEYkHYlpKcX9h/C8zxWKkUBUWdqcJTL5wUoIFM/MHAVi0E4HnXgfgOBaFIKgTgGdLDWA5GsDYu4dg8FIAQTQ3KVhCRAHnDQ%2BhOCSAFUqkVnBeAKBABqxVQruWkDgLAJAmBVBQkCWQCgEAGjAAUMoQwVQhAIFQJrQV8q65JDoOeDIrqQi0A9V6n1vA/V0AGMALgZg2hRvoMQAA8i7MN3rdXWqhA8Ygzr9WkCzcgOo%2BBBW8H4FzUQ4gpAyEEIoFQ6hTWkF0G0AwRgUDWGsPoPAERDWQBWKgIqGRDUcHNpyGOpgJWWC4HiI45sADqYhaCzrnda%2B8s6rLoEMI4ZA5tojEqfMuzdRgO7AHNikfi0RZ3JrMAa6Vmw9CcmCMG91nqM2NuDJgLY8rNbYSSJwHgPK%2BU6sbaKjg2AbW/kTEcVQgxYjm1iJIb%2ByBkBHDjeErgptxWwpsEcXAhASDfjlUsXgJqtBLBVWqjVvKODatIIK4VoGDVGoVUq8jmqOA3ro7qxjLHTVsYghkEAkggA%3D)

As far as I can tell there's nothing wrong with the code above.

A pointer is made to a variable that exists on the stack but that pointer is deleted when the local variable is deleted so nothing is dangling AFAICT.

I'm am missing where the dangling pointer is? Is this a bug in GCC? Is there some quirk of C++ I'm unaware of that's being triggered here? Is this just a limitation of what's possible it check for and I need to disable the warning?

Note: there is `printStack` and there is a macro removing it

```
#define printStack(msg)
```

if I remove the macro so that `printStack` is actually used the warning goes away which seems to suggest this is a gcc bug?

Comment: Does the warning go away if you do something about this horrendous line: `nodeStack = { str, &oldNodeStack };`? I mean, which `nodeStack` do you think you're using: the member with that name or the parameter with that name?

Comment: It will be helpful and reduce our efforts if you show the line where the warning is raised on.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it. GCC supports `-Wdangling-pointer` only since the last release 12.1 and with that I can't get it to produce the warning on compiler explorer, see https://godbolt.org/z/P4GY3TvP3.

Comment: What version of GCC are you using, and on what OS?

Comment: You need to keep in mind this is a static analysis. It doesn’t matter how the code works, all that matters is how the compiler sees it. In my experience GCC 12 needs some love wrt it’s static analysis. I myself have lodged a false positive bug one one of its new static analysis.

Comment: In the constructor you have `oldNodeStack(nodeStack)`. That makes a copy of the `ConsList` copying the `value` and the `tail`. So now you have 2 lists sharing a tail. How are you going to free the lists? You need a `shared_ptr` or a deep copy constructor there.

Comment: my bad, I made the smaller repo, couldn't find a place to run it on gcc-12 and assumed it would generate the warning. I've changed the code in the question to something that does generate the warning.